# @nextLink broken on Outlook REST API with $search

Tags: outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am searching 'my mailbox' with Outlook REST API (beta endpoint) with the following request

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/messages/?$search=test`

so far so good I retrieve a list of relevant items. It looks that there is a continuation link in the `@nextLink` property

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/messages/?$search=test&$top=10&$skiptoken=<bigTokenHere>`

But invoking this one fails with the following message

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQuery","message":"The following parameters are not supported with change tracking over the 'Messages' resource: '$search'."}}
```

Is that normal behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yep, that's a bug on our end. We're tracking it.

Comment: frustating enough I get this `"Unable to cast object of type 'LegacyPagingToken' to type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.SkipToken'."` when removing `$search` as the message tells that the additional param is breaking the things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, so it should start working across tenants.